# Decrypt error using simplecrypt

Tags: node.js

I am new to nodejs,sails and need to encrypt some data before storing it in the database.

I have found the module [simplecrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simplecrypt)

And have made this code demo.

```
var simplecrypt = require("simplecrypt");

var sc = simplecrypt();
var digest = sc.encrypt("my secret");
console.log(digest); // "66cea6eb1c18b8862485cf0604fa6062" 

var message = sc.decrypt(digest);
console.log(message); // "my secret"
```

It does encrypt the value, but when I attempt to decrypt I get an error:

```
crypto.js:202 
    var ret = this._handle.final();
                          ^
Error: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
    at Error (native)
    at Decipher.Cipher.final (crypto.js:202:26)
```

Can someone suggest a way for me to correctly decrypt my encrypted value?

Comment: I copy/pasted this code into my editor and was able to run it successfully. (without Sails)

Comment: the error that you are receiving means that the key that you passed into sc.decrypt is invalid/incorrect.

Comment: Thanks  danypaz, what key I can pass to sc.decrypt? That error appear when i encrypt user.password in function in Model User.js beforeCreate: function(user, cb) {
       
        user.password = sc.encrypt(user.password);;
        cb();
    } and then in passport.js i decrpt var passdecrpt= sc.decrypt(user.password); after that i compare password that i input and passdecrpt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spend all day for checking, I foud out the result. 
I have to define

```
var user1 ={
  method:methodinput,
  password:passwordinput,
  salt:saltinput
};
```

and assign values get from mydabase to user1 and declare

```
 var sc = simplecrypt(user1);
 var passEncrypt = sc.encrypt(passworduserinput);
```

then compare user.password with passEncrypt.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment @angel, I think I understand where your issue lies. decrypt() takes the hash of a String, instead of the String (user.password) itself.

```
var simplecrypt = require("simplecrypt");
var sc = simplecrypt();

var user = {
  password: "password123"
};

var myHash = sc.encrypt(user.password);

// myHash returns a hash of user.password

console.log(myHash); // "66cea6eb1c18b8862485cf0604fa6062" 

// This next state
// You will need to pass the created hash into decrypt
var message = sc.decrypt("66cea6eb1c18b8862485cf0604fa6062");
console.log(message); // "password123"
```

If you were trying to validate that a user has signed in (assuming this from user.password), you would want to compare the password with the stored hash from the database.

```
// Here is a simple example for a login screen
// (Not for use in production)
var simplecrypt = require("simplecrypt");
var sc = simplecrypt();

var user = {
  password: "password123"
};

// This would be stored in the DB
var databaseHash = sc.encrypt(user.password);

// Here is your login function
//
// Now when the user logs in, you will compare the two
// and see if the credentials match
var userInput = sc.encrypt(user.password);
var usersPasswordFromDatabase = databaseHash;

if (userInput === usersPasswordFromDatabase){
  // Logged In!
  console.log('Logged In!');
}else {
  console.log('Invalid Username/Password');
}
```

The example will returned 'Logged In'

Comment: Hi danypaz, The problem was value I passed to decrypt(), it is a hash and i findOne it in my database. I don't know why value get from db, that make error.

Comment: Your example will not run when databaseHast that get from database and it is a has. I try and compare password that i input  with databaseHast  but they are  not equal. var userInput = sc.encrypt(user.password);
var usersPasswordFromDatabase = databaseHash;
if (userInput === usersPasswordFromDatabase){
  // Logged In!
}else {
  // Invalid User/Password.
}

Comment: I had a typo in my example (user1 instead of user).

Comment: If you are still having issues, please post the code you are using into your original post

Comment: Thank you, dannypaz, after check I saw the problem of me was, when iIencrypted a password and inserted  into database, simplecrypt auto get key for encrypt, and if i just decrypt it will be true, but when i query password from database and compare so it's false because simplecrypt have another key? Can you suggest me a solution?